# ¿Cómo resuelvo este error IllegalStateException usando Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Tengo un error en mi aplicación estoy utilizando `thymeleaf` con `spring boot`

```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
> target object for bean name 'personModel' available as request
> attribute     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:401)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:328)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:294)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.java:98)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
> ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
```

En mi controller tengo este método:

```
@PostMapping("/addperson")
public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute(name="personModel") PersonModel personModel,
        Model model){
    LOG.info("METHOD: addPerson()--PARAMS:"+personModel.toString());

    if (null!= personService.addPerson(personModel)){
        model.addAttribute("result", 1);
    }else {
        model.addAttribute("result",0);
    }

    return "redirect:/personas/personasMAV";
}
```

En mi vista tengo esto:

```
 <form role="form" action="" th:action="@{/personas/addperson}"
 th:object="${personModel}" method="POST">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="apaPaterno" id="apaPaterno" th:field="*{Appaterno}" class="form-control input-sm"
 placeholder="Apellido Paterno" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="apaMaterno" id="apaMaterno" th:field="*{Apmaterno}" class="form-control input-sm"
 placeholder="Apellido Materno" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

---

```
<form role="form" action="" th:action="@{/personas/addperson}" th:object="${personModel}" method="POST">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="apaPaterno" id="apaPaterno" th:field="*{Appaterno}" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="apaMaterno" id="apaMaterno" th:field="*{Apmaterno}" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Apellido Materno" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

Comment: Prueba varias cosas, por un lado quita Model model como parámetro del controlador y añade esta línea dentro del método:
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(nombre de tu vista)

dentro de la vista, quita el from role y el action y usa directamente form action = "form" y cierra el form si no lo estás cerrando.

Yo tengo un post así y funciona perfectamente, si te sirve de algo avisa y creo una respuesta más elaborada.

Comment: Amigos muchas gracias, ya lo solucioné solo me faltaba agregar el atributo en el ModelAndView.

Comment: @GetMapping("/personasNatural")
 public ModelAndView personasNatural(Model model){
  LOG.info("INGRESANDO AL METODO : personasNatural");
  model.addAttribute("personModel",new PersonModel());
  return new ModelAndView(ViewConstant.PERSONA_NATURAL);
 }

Answer (score 0):

El error es bastante claro, no puede encontrar desde la vista el bean correspondiente para funcionar ya que no lo has indicado en el controlador. En el caso del POST, lo ideal sería utilizar el objeto ModelAndView en lugar del Model que usas.

```
@PostMapping("/addperson")
public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute(name="personModel") PersonModel 
personModel){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(NOMBRE_VISTA)
}
```

Con este cambio, consigues conectar tu vista al modelo y que Spring sepa localizar los distintos atributos que estás seteando. Posteriormente, añades cada atributo dentro del model:

```
model.addAtribute(NOMBRE_ATRIBUTO)
```

Con esto lo que permites a Spring es que ese atributo pueda ser encontrado dentro de la vista. Spring gestiona toda la configuración por ti pero tienes que indicarle dónde va cada cosa.